# Reset rxjs interval on click in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, rxjs6

A simple question regarding intervals in RxJS - I have made a carousel where slides change every minute and there is a detail that dissatisfies me. When the slide is switched manually by user to next or previous - interval will still change the slide automatically but in *whatever time there's left till interval fires off the new value*, so it disregards anything what the user did. How can I make interval know if the user changed the slide, and only from user action count a minute and then change slide automatically. Other times interval should work automatically as regular.

Will be happy to hear ideas, thanks!!!

Here's what I got:

```
  source = interval(10000);

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.source.subscribe(() => this.slide('forward'));
  }

  slide(option): void {
    switch (option) {
      case 'forward':
        this.currentSlide === this.SLIDES.length - 1 ?
          this.currentSlide = DEFAULT_SLIDE : this.currentSlide++;
        break;
      case 'back':
        this.currentSlide === DEFAULT_SLIDE ?
          this.currentSlide = this.SLIDES.length - 1 : this.currentSlide--;
        break;
    }
  }
```

Template:

```
<div class="sliderNav">
    <mat-icon (click)="slide('back')">keyboard_arrow_up</mat-icon>
    <p>{{currentSlide + 1}}/{{SLIDES.length}}</p>
    <mat-icon (click)="slide('forward')">keyboard_arrow_down</mat-icon>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

I would say RxJS is overkill for this behavior. It could be achieved using plain JS [`setTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout) function. Moreover you aren't closing the subscription when the component is destroyed which might lead to a memory leak.

#### Option 1: JS `setTimeout()`

```js
timeoutId: number;

ngOnInit(): void {
  this.resetTimer();      // <-- start timer when the component is created
}

resetTimer() {
  if (!!this.timeoutId) {             // <-- Update: clear the timeout
    clearTimeout(this.timeoutId);
  }
  this.timeoutId = setTimeout(() => this.slide('forward'), 10000);
}

/**
 * Reset the timer each time `slide()` function is triggered:
 *   1. When the `setTimeout()` triggers the callback
 *   2. When the user changes the slide manually
 */
slide(option): void {
  this.resetTimer();       // <-- reset timer here

  switch (option) {
    case 'forward':
      this.currentSlide === this.SLIDES.length - 1 ?
        this.currentSlide = DEFAULT_SLIDE : this.currentSlide++;
      break;
    case 'back':
      this.currentSlide === DEFAULT_SLIDE ?
        this.currentSlide = this.SLIDES.length - 1 : this.currentSlide--;
      break;
  }
}

ngOnDestroy() {
  clearTimeout(this.timeoutId);      // <-- clear the timeout when the component is destroyed
}
```

#### Option 2: RxJS `interval()`

If you insist on using RxJS, you'd need to mind multiple things

1. Obtain the manual inputs from the user using either a multi-cast observable like `ReplaySubject` (shown here) or using a template reference variable with `fromEvent` function (not shown).
2. Use `switchMap` operator to map from one observable to another. `switchMap` cancels/closes the inner observable when the outer observable emits. This way the timer would be regenerated.
3. Close the subscription in the `ngOnDestroy()` hook to avoid memory leaks from open subscriptions. Illustrated here using the `takeUntil` operator.

**Controller (*.ts)**

```js
import { ReplaySubject } from 'rxjs';
import { map, switchMap, takeUntil } from 'rxjs/operators';

clickEvents$ = new ReplaySubject<string>(1);   // <-- buffer 1
closed$ = new ReplaySubject<any>(1);

ngOnInit() {
  this.clickEvents$.asObservable.pipe(
    switchMap((event: string) => interval(10000).pipe(    // <-- cancel inner subscription when outer subscription emits
      map(() => event)                         // <-- map back to the event
    )),
    takeUntil(this.closed$)
  ).subscribe(this.slide.bind(this));          // <-- use `bind()` to preserve `this` in callback
}

slide(option): void {
  switch (option) {
    case 'forward':
      this.currentSlide === this.SLIDES.length - 1 ?
        this.currentSlide = DEFAULT_SLIDE : this.currentSlide++;
      break;
    case 'back':
      this.currentSlide === DEFAULT_SLIDE ?
        this.currentSlide = this.SLIDES.length - 1 : this.currentSlide--;
      break;
  }
}

ngOnDestroy() {
  this.closed$.next();                          // <-- close open subscriptions
}
```

**Template (*.html)**

```html
<button (click)="clickEvent$.next('back')">Back</button>
<button (click)="clickEvent$.next('forward')">Forward</button>
```

Comment: Hello, Michael! Thanks for the extended answer! I like the setTimeout solution - it is close to how I initially planned the slider(though I tried using setInterval, but then for whatever reason decided to try doing it with the help of rxjs :D ) One small note - I believe we need to clear the timeout before resetting it in slide(), right? Otherwise it will just create a new timer and they will both work at their own time(at least that's what happened to me when I tried):D Once again - thank you very much indeed, I highly appreciate your answers!

Comment: @Kateryna: Yes you're right. The reason it's called `resetTimer` and not `setTimer` is because the existing timeout needs to be closed. Thanks for the message. I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

## Merging streams with RxJS

A possible solution is to create streams from your button click events and merge them together.

You can then use switchMap to reset your interval every time a source emits. Here's how that might look.

```
<div class="sliderNav">
    <mat-icon #slideBack>keyboard_arrow_up</mat-icon>
    <p>{{currentSlide + 1}}/{{SLIDES.length}}</p>
    <mat-icon #slideForward>keyboard_arrow_down</mat-icon>
</div>
```

```ts
intervalTime = 10000;

@ViewChild('slideBack', {static: true}) 
slideBack: ElementRef;

@ViewChild('slideForward', {static: true}) 
slideForward: ElementRef;

ngOnInit(): void {

  const [first$, forward$, interval$] = [
    timer(intervalTime),
    fromEvent(slideForward, 'click'),
    interval(intervalTime)
  ].map(v => v.pipe(
    mapTo("forward")
  ));

  const backward$ = fromEvent(slideBack, 'click').pipe(
    mapTo("backward")
  );

  merge(first$, forward$, backward$).pipe(
    switchMap(option => interval$.pipe(
      startWith(option)
    ))
  ).subscribe(option => {

    switch (option) {
      case 'forward':
        this.currentSlide === this.SLIDES.length - 1 ?
          this.currentSlide = DEFAULT_SLIDE : this.currentSlide++;
        break;
      case 'backward':
        this.currentSlide === DEFAULT_SLIDE ?
          this.currentSlide = this.SLIDES.length - 1 : this.currentSlide--;
        break;
    }

  })
}
```

Comment: `document.getElementById()` is not recommended in Angular since it'd crawl the entire app's DOM to search for the element. Instead a combination of template reference variable + `@ViewChild` would eliminate the overhead from such searches.

Comment: I don't use angular myself, so I've updated with what I think you're talking about. Let me know if that's what you were imagining.